# How to create a dataframe from my output in R console

Tags: r

Good evening,

I am struggling to save a dataframe to my Global environment. I ran a code and surprisingly it gave exactly the output that I want, however, the output is only shown in my R console. I want to save the output as a new dataframe. How can I do that?

My code is shown below and the result is also shown. Hope anyone can help me.
[See my console and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm66h.png)

My code is as follows:

```
active_time <- as.data.frame(auditlogs_total)
auditlogs1[, grp2 := (seq_len(.N)+1) %/% 2, by = subject]
auditlogs1[, time_diff := difftime(timestamp, shift(timestamp), unit = "min"), by = .(subject, grp2)]
auditlogs1[ , .(total.time = sum(time_diff, na.rm = T)+1), by = .(userId,date_component, subject)]
save(newdata1.rds)
```

I thought that the sentence "newdata <- as.data.frame(auditlogs_total)" would save the desired result. However, it only saves auditlogs_total including the time_diff as "active_time". How can I save the output from the console with the userId's, date_component, subject, and total.time as a separate dataframe?

Comment: Your first line `active_time <- as.data.frame(auditlogs_total)` makes a copy of `auditlogs_total` in its current state. Neither `active_time` nor `auditlogs_total` are mentioned again, so this seems irrelevant. Your next two lines use `:=` in `data.table` syntax, so you are actively modifying `auditlogs1`, adding the `grp2` and `time_diff` columns. Your next line with `total.time` doesn't use `:=` or `<-`, so it will print the result but not save it anywhere. If you want to save the results of that line, assign it to something, `auditlogs_total <- auditlogs1[ , .(total.time = sum(...`.

Comment: Then your last line `save(newdata1.rds)` is confusing. `newdata1.rds` has never been mentioned before, so I'm not sure what you're hoping it int. `save` tries to write an object to a file on your computer, it needs both the name of the R object and the name of the file, so something like `save(auditlogs_total, file = "my auiditlogs filename.rds")` would be expected.

Comment: It's also confusing that you say `auditlogs_total` is saved, but `auditlogs_total` isn't mentioned in your code at all... seems like some information is missing.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas. I understand your confusion. The line save(newdata1.rds) was a desperate shot to save it. Obviously, it didn't work. I looked at your comment and it made me think about the code again. And you are totally correct. I modified my code and it successfully worked. I now have a new dataframe with the desired output! Thanks for your input, without it, I wouldn't be seeing the mistakes haha.

This is the updated code:

Comment: auditlogs_total[, grp2 := (seq_len(.N)+1) %/% 2, by = subject]
auditlogs_total[, time_diff := difftime(timestamp, shift(timestamp), unit = "min"), by = .(subject, grp2)]
activetime <- auditlogs_total[ , .(total.time = sum(time_diff, na.rm = T)+1), by = .(userId,date_component, subject)]

Comment: You don't have a data.frame but a data.table which is a fundamentally different library and class object which in most steps does not require assignment, `<-` like data frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, your issue is the assignment operation in the `data.table` library, a third-party package where its `data.table` class extends `base` R's `data.frame` class object. Specifically, when you use the assignment by reference operator, `:=`, to add, remove, or update columns the return value is a modified version of the whole data.table itself. Per [docs](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/assign.html):

> **Value**
> DT is modified by reference and returned invisibly. If you require a copy, take a copy first (using DT2 = copy(DT)).

Therefore, as @GregorThomas comments, continue using the assignment by reference operator, `:=`, in all steps and your resulting data.table (not data.frame) object, `auditlogs1`, will persist with changes. By the way, you can chain your steps. See helpful [data.table vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).

```r
auditlogs1[, 
      grp2 := (seq_len(.N)+1) %/% 2, 
      by = subject
    ][, 
      time_diff := difftime(timestamp, shift(timestamp), unit = "min"), 
      by = .(subject, grp2)
    ][, 
      total.time := sum(time_diff, na.rm = TRUE) + 1,
      by = .(userId, date_component, subject)
    ]
```

Should you then need to save, use built-in `base` R save functions to save entire environment of objects or single object to file system or disk.

```r
# RDA/RData (ALL OBJECTS in GLOBAL ENV
save(list=ls(), "/path/to/mydata.RData")           

# RDA/RData (ALL OBJECTS in GLOBAL ENV, WRAPPER FOR ABOVE)
save.image("/path/to/mydata.RData")   

# RDA/RData (SPECIFIC OBJECT IN GLOBAL ENV)
save(auditlogs1, file="/path/to/auditlogs1.rda")     

# RDS (SPECIFIC OBJECT IN GLOBAL ENV)
saveRDS(auditlogs1, file="/path/to/auditlogs1.rds")
```